# Connection to Oracle database via Visual Studio Server Explorer crashes Visual Studio

Tags: windows-7, visual-studio-2010

I am trying to create an ADO.Net entity Data Model of an existing oracle 11g database, however I cannot even get past the step of Database Connection.

Every time I attempt to test the connection Visual Studio closes without any details as to the error. Just this screen

[image: Error Image]

I am using following:

Visual Studio 2010 Ultimate

.NET 4.0.3

Oracle 11g client

ODAC 11.2.0.3

Windows 7

Any help is appreciated. Thank you

**EDIT :**

***This what I got from Event viewer of windows:***

Faulting application name: devenv.exe, version: 10.0.40219.1, time stamp: 0x4d5f2a73

Faulting module name: oran11.dll, version: 11.2.0.1, time stamp: 0x4bb34692

Exception code: 0xc0000005

Fault offset: 0x0028deee

Faulting process id: 0x2020

Faulting application start time: 0x01cd5f6aa0a48f4f

Faulting application path: C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\Common7\IDE\devenv.exe

Faulting module path: C:\app\User\product\11.2.0\client_2\bin\oran11.dll

Report Id: c2394ba8-cb5e-11e1-8347-005056c00008

Comment: This is not the right place for this question.  It belongs on either StackOverflow or SuperUser.  This site is designed for system admin questions, not development or desktop debugging (unless its for all of your desktops).

Comment: @BrentPabst Thank you for notifying me. How could I migrate my question to SuperUser?

Comment: If you ever need a Question migrated just Flag it and explain why/where. A mod will take care of it. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This occurs when you install the ODAC into an existing Oracle Home.The **OCI.DLL** in your `Oracle_Home` was locked during the installation and was not overwritten.The **OCI.DLL** is now old and out of synch with the other DLLs, hence the crash.

The easiest solution is to simply reinstall into a new `Oracle_Home` (directory). If you must use the same `Oracle_Home` name and directory, you will still need to delete the now corrupted  `Oracle_home` and then reinstall, using the following steps:

- Use the installer to uninstall the entire oracle home that is
  crashing.
- Look at the home in windows explorer. **oci.dll** should still be there.
- Rename **oci.dll** to **oci.toanything**.
- Reboot machine.
- Go back to windows explorer and delete all remaining files in the
  oracle home, including **oci.toanything**.
- Install ODAC.

Hope it helps.