# IIS app pool is shutting down when connecting to Oracle DSN?

Tags: windows-7, database, iis

I am trying to connect to the Oracle database using the `DSN` in my web application and when I browse the site the app pool crashes. The DSN is set up correctly I think because when I hit Test connection it successfully connects. When I looked at the `Event viewer` If found the Application Error with below details,

```
Faulting application name: w3wp.exe, version: 7.5.7601.17514, time stamp: 0x4ce7a5f8
Faulting module name: oracommon11.dll, version: 11.2.0.1, time stamp: 0x4bb5eab3
Exception code: 0xc00000fd
Fault offset: 0x000f7ac0
Faulting process id: 0x1fa8
Faulting application start time: 0x01d0c88b19a0096c
Faulting application path: C:\Windows\SysWOW64\inetsrv\w3wp.exe
Faulting module path: C:\app\Administrator\product\11.2.0\client_1\BIN\oracommon11.dll
Report Id: 5ab8a5bc-347e-11e5-9b7b-d067e50cb873
```

I found [this](https://superuser.com/questions/447713/connection-to-oracle-database-via-visual-studio-server-explorer-crashes-visual-s?newreg=5c21f056e9814e3d883cc1f5b6bc8589) pretty similar but it is similar not exactly my exception. So I am confused. Any help would be great to resolve this issue.

Comment: 0xc00000fd is a stack overflow. Does the application use any recursive methods in its global.asax?

Comment: No not any recursive methods. But when I connect the same application on other IIS using other Oracle server installation then it works just fine. But on this particular machine with Oracle server is giving me this issue

Comment: Well, since the error is occuring within the oracle common dll, check your oracle client installation. Also, is this a user DSN? if so, is it accessible to the application pool identity user?

Comment: No it is System DSN. Yes it is accessible to the application pool identity user.